Gravity Forms User Registration - Add user to a specific BuddyBoss group
We are using BuddyBoss to manage our community of Schools, Teachers and Parents.
At the moment we have the Schools each set up as their own individual Group. I want to build the functionality which would allow a School (group) to send out a registration form for Parents to create their own login to the site which would give them school-specific content.
I can't find a way to do this within BB, therefore i'm looking to Gravity Forms User Registration, but not sure how to assign the user to the respective Group ID?
Thanks
Tom
